# Flutter - Dart - Reflectable package : how to: instantiate classes using GlobalQuantifyCapability

Tags: flutter, dart

const PrivacyReflectable()
: super(GlobalQuantifyCapability("farah", PrivacyReflectable));

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this (parts of) code:

```
// @dart=2.10

import 'package:reflectable/reflectable.dart';

import 'main4.reflectable.dart';

void main() {
  initializeReflectable();
  final fooClass = reflector.reflectType(Foo) as ClassMirror;
  final foo = fooClass.newInstance('', const []) as Foo;
  print(foo.runtimeType);
  print(foo.s);
}

const reflector = Reflector();

@reflector
class Foo {
  String s = 'I am foo';
}

class Reflector extends Reflectable {
  const Reflector()
      : super(
            declarationsCapability,
            invokingCapability,
            subtypeQuantifyCapability,
            typeAnnotationDeepQuantifyCapability,
            typeCapability,
            typeRelationsCapability);
}
```

Result:

```
Foo
I am foo
```

P.S.

This answer has nothing to do with `GlobalQuantifyCapability`.
So maybe this doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Thanks for your reply mezoni i see this answer before but what i exactly want is to instantiate the class foo with a string  what if i have like 10 classes i dont want to each class by its name i need one method reflect that take a string and return the instantiation Thanks for your help